# How to correctly set up session with everyauth and express?

Tags: facebook, node.js, session, express, everyauth

I am trying to build a simple nodejs app that can log in with facebook using express and everyauth. Following the README tutorial [here](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth), I've performed the following setup in app.js:

```
var everyauth = require('everyauth');

everyauth.facebook
    .appId('829428097067274')
    .appSecret('2c4d4a96514aa8374fbc54d611945148')
    .findOrCreateUser(function (session, accessToken, accessTokExtra, fbUserMetadata) {
        // I will fill this in with something real later, but for now
        // I just want something that works with a fake session

        console.log("in find or create user")

        // this is always undefined...
        console.log(session);

        // these look good; I'm getting real user info
        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(accessTokExtra);
        console.log(fbUserMetadata);

        // I'm not sure what I need to return here. I've tried
        // variations of this.Promise()/promise.fulfill() as well
        return { id: 100, session: "the session" };
    })
    .redirectPath('/');

// ...

// this gives an error saying that session is no longer
// bundled with express, but I'm not sure which package to replace
// it with:
// app.use(express.session());

app.use(everyauth.middleware(app));
```

When I launch my app, I visit localhost:3000/auth/facebook, which correctly redirects to facebook. I authorize the app there, which redirects me to localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback. However, here my app logs an error of:

`Step getSession of`facebook`is promising: session ; however, the step returns nothing. Fix the step by returning the expected values OR by returning a Promise that promises said values.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try enabling debugging as described on the project page: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth#debugging---logging-module-steps

Comment: Also, there is at least one facebook issue in the queue and another with express 4 compatibility...you might want to look at the issues queue.  Everyauth has not been updated actively in a long time.  You may want to investigate things like Passport or other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but still talk about this that I also struggled with `everyauth` and `express 4.x`.

If you are using `express 4.x`, install `express-session` by `npm install express-session`

using the following code, some other code is the same as the example by the everyauth.

```
var session = require('express-session');
...
var app = express();
app.use(session({secret : "anything you want"}));
app.use(everyauth.middleware());
```